How to read in a ps-file figur (file.ps) in LaTeX
I have read many questions about how to compile a ps-figure file in LaTeX and have tried all answers, but I can not run the file, and get error msg. Here is one of those files:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epsf}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{figure}[]
\hspace{-1.5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{FIG1.ps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The FIG1.ps file can be downloaded here.
I use TeXworks with MiKTeX.

rename it to FIG1.eps. That is cheating (it isn't an eps) but seems to work. Or use ghostscript to make an eps.

you only neeed graphicx do not load epsf or epstopdf packages for new documents

Just a note: If you get an error message, you should always show the error message. For LaTeX errors you should copy&paste the error message from the log file as code to your question,

Unfortunately download of the linked file fails with: Connecting to home.hvl.no (home.hvl.no)|158.37.24.47|:443... connected. … Unable to establish SSL connection.. So I cannot test using this file,

Thank you for all answeres. I did not manage to rename it to eps (I am not working on linux and even if I change name, .ps tag is there) @cobohah if you send me email, I can enclose the Fig1.ps as answer: ahas@hvl.no . I eliminated epsf and epstopdf and get this error message as I got with them: ''' ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
...
l.23 \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{FIG1.ps} '''

I run this:\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{FIG1.ps} \end{document} and then get error: ```Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
...
l.4 \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{FIG1.ps}   ```   COULD YOU PLEASE RUN THE CODE YOURSELF? thank you!

Your code woks fine for me, if possible, please post the error (.log) file for further analysing
